Cognito user signup does not throw UsernameExistsException
I have a cognito instance where I need it to throw UsernameExistsException error whenever you try to sign up a new user with an email which is already associated with a user.
Based on documentation, this can be enabled in CDK with preventUserExistenceErrors: false or PreventUserExistenceErrors:LEGACY if using cloudformation.
My cognito instance only has email as user attribute.
Whenever I try to sign up a user with an existing email, I am still not getting a UsernameExistsException.
Any ideas why? I'm about to give up on cognito
